IpcResponse Tauri
I am very new to Rust and tauri
My objective with this code is to fetch a list of gamas from a db and pass that list to tauri
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

use sqlx::{PgPool, postgres::PgPoolOptions};
use time::Date;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Gama {
    //all values are string,
    validate_ot_date : Option<Date>,
}
impl Default for Gama {
    fn default() -> Self {
       //all values are none
    }
}

This is the fn where I got the error.
I also tried to return Gama but the got an error in await?
#[tauri::command]
async fn fetch_data() -> Result<Vec<Gama>,sqlx::Error> {

        async fn get_gama(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<Vec<Gama>, sqlx::Error> {
            let gamas = sqlx::query_as!(
                Gama,
                r#"
                SELECT 
                    ot_ref, sub_ot_1, sub_ot_2, sub_ot_3, sub_ot_4, 
                    validate_ot_colaborador, validate_ot_date::DATE as "validate_ot_date?"
                FROM tabela_ots"#
            )
            .fetch_all(pool)
            .await?;
        
            Ok(gamas)
        }
        //I dont know why but variable comes from .env file
        let database_url = "postgres://";
        let pool = PgPoolOptions::new().connect(database_url).await?;

        let gamas = get_gama(&pool).await?;
        print!("{:#?}", &gamas);

        //if gamas is = to Result<Vec<Gama> gamas=gamas if gamas = sqlx::error gamas = gamas.default()

        Ok(gamas)
    }

this is the main fn
fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![fetch_data])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

When I run this code i got this error
 |
 | #[tauri::command]
 | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&Vec<Gama>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
...
 |         .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![extract_data])
 |                         -------------------------------------- in this macro invocation

I tried to add use tauri::IpcResponse;
 | #[derive(Debug, Clone, IpcResponse)]
 |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
 |
note: `IpcResponse` is imported here, but it is only a trait, without a derive macro


Everything you return from commands must implement serde::Serialize (this also includes the error type) https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serialize.html - for errors Tauri has a introduction guide: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command#error-handling
